# If $\int e^x(2\sin^3x+3\sin2x)\sin x dx=e^x\cdot(\phi(x))+c$ then which of the following is false?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

> If $\int e^x(2\sin^3x+3\sin2x)\sin x dx=e^x\cdot(\phi(x))+c$ then which of the following is false?
>
> - A) $\phi(\frac{\pi}2)=2$
> - B) $\phi(\pi)=0$
> - C) $\phi(\frac{\pi}6)=\frac12$
> - D) $\phi(0)=0$

I tried rearranging it so that I could put $\sin x$ or $\cos x$ as $t$, but couldn't reach anywhere.

I tried separating the two integrals and then integrating by parts, that didn't work either.

I tried to make it in the form $\int e^x(f(x)+f'(x))dx$ but in vain.

By looking at the options, it appears $\phi(x)$ could be $\sin x$ then options $B, C, D$ would satisfy but $A$ wouldn't. I am not sure though.

Comment: Are you certain you've typed it correctly?  I couldn't see how to do it, and I integrated it in [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+e%5Ex%282sin%5E3x%2B3sin%282x%29%29sin%28x%29) to see if I could figure out what was going on, but all the statements appear to be false.  (My first thought was to differentiate both sides, but that introduces $\phi'(x)$ and I can't see how one would deal with that.)

Comment: @saulspatz, yes, I have typed the question verbatim.

Comment: @saulspatz, I too just tried it at wolfram alpha. Looks like the statement is indeed incorrect. Sorry to have bothered you all.

Comment: Hint : To evaluate the integral use $\sin x=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$.

Comment: @Nikhil Kumar Singh, I tried doing that substitution. I am getting a lot of exponential terms. Are you sure this hint is giving a solution? Because [wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint+e%5Ex%282%5Csin%5E3x%2B3%5Csin%282x%29%29%5Csin+x+dx) is giving a different result.